# fopen: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html, txt

Ola estou começando a aprender PHP, e criei um input HTML que recebe um arquivo TXT que deve ser lido no PHP porem estou tendo dificuldades na parte de ler o arquivo do input, que me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: fopen(teste.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache2\htdocs\teste.php on line 8
```

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver?

Meu código:
(index.php)

```
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <form action="teste.php" method="post">
        <label for="myfile">coloque seu arquivo:</label>
        <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

(teste.php)

```
<html>
<body>

Arquivo txt:  <?php echo $_POST["myfile"]; ?><br>

<?php
$input_txt =$_POST["myfile"]; 
// Abre o Arquvio no Modo r (para leitura)
$arquivo = fopen ($input_txt, 'r');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O `fopen` só funcionaria se o arquivo já estivesse salvo no diretório do projeto. Você precisa pegar os dados do arquivo pelo $_FILES.

Comment: E você teria alguma dica de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Postei a resposta abaixo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que seu txt tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```
João,joao@joao.com.br,125
Maria,maria@maria.com.br,123
```

Primeiro no formulário você precisa adicionar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` como atributo para você poder enviar arquivos. Depois você precisa pegar o array que é gerado quando você envia um aquivo `$_FILES['myfile']`, esse array tem 5 itens, `name, type, tmp_name, error e size`, no seu caso você vai precisa do `tmp_name`, ficando assim:

```
$myfile = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
```

Agora é só tratar os dados:

```
//file — Lê todo o arquivo para um array
$dados = file($myfile );

foreach($dados as $linha){
   
   $ln_valor = explode(',', $linha); //Explode na virgula
   
   $nome = $valor[0];
   $email = $valor[1];
   $id = $valor[2];

}
```